# Bind style to subcomponents in synth

Tags: java, swing, synth

Is it ever possible to bind custom styles to a component's subcomponents?

For example in my case, I have a `JTabbedPane` on which I set the name "MyPopup". I would like to bind a specific style to it's `tabbedPaneTabArea` by doing this:

```
<bind style="MyTabbedPaneTabArea" type="name" key="TabbedPaneTabArea.MyPopup" />.
```

This seems to not work and I've spent quite some time googling around.

Comment: Please provide the code what you have

Comment: This works for Synthetica L&F which is based on Synth L&F. But I never used Synth L&F directly, so I cannot say whether it really works.

Comment: Actually I'm using Synthetica but didn't manage to make it working.  The style is actually very staightforward: just draw a image on the TabbedPaneTabArea.  It works only if I bind type="region" but this applies to every TabbedPaneTabArea instance.

Comment: <style id="tabbedPaneTabArea">
        <insets top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0" />
        <state>
            <imagePainter method="tabbedPaneTabAreaBorder"
                path="/gui/laf/images/internalFrameTitlePaneBackground.png" sourceInsets="0 0 0 0"
                paintCenter="true" stretch="true" />
        </state>
    </style>
    <bind style="tabbedPaneTabArea" type="name" key="TabbedPaneTabArea.MyPopup" />